# Problem updating AppGw when WAF Policy is assigned : ApplicationGatewayWafConfigurationCannotBeChangedWithWafPolicy

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

While trying to update an application gateway (to add a backend pool), using the following command :

```
az network application-gateway address-pool create --gateway-name "***" --resource-group "***" --servers "***" --name "***"
```

I get the following error

```
(ApplicationGatewayWafConfigurationCannotBeChangedWithWafPolicy) WebApplicationFirewallConfiguration cannot be changed when there is a WAF Policy /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/*** associated with it.
Code: ApplicationGatewayWafConfigurationCannotBeChangedWithWafPolicy
Message: WebApplicationFirewallConfiguration cannot be changed when there is a WAF Policy /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/*** associated with it.
```

I did a similar change a few days ago and I didn't get any error.

I tried doing the change in the Portal and I get the same error.

I tried disabling the WAF rule but I get the same error.

Any clue? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> (ApplicationGatewayWafConfigurationCannotBeChangedWithWafPolicy)WebApplicationFirewallConfiguration cannot be changed when there is a WAF Policy/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/***associated with it. Code:ApplicationGatewayWafConfigurationCannotBeChangedWithWafPolicy Message: WebApplicationFirewallConfiguration cannot be changed when there is a WAF Policy
> /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies/*** associated with it.

The error occurs could be because some parameters related to the WAF policy are missing from the Application Gateway configuration.

> ```
> 1.  `$SubscriptionId =  'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx'`
> 2.  `$ResourceGroupName =  'RGname'`
> 3.  `$GatewayName =  'appgwname'`
> 4.  `Connect-AzAccount  -Subscription $SubscriptionId`
> 5.  `$appGw =  Get-AzApplicationGateway  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $GatewayName`
> 6.  `$appGw.FirewallPolicy  = $null`
> 7.  `$appGw.Sku.Name  =  'Standard_v2'`
> 8.  `$appGw.Sku.Tier  =  'Standard_v2'`
> 9.  `$appGw.WebApplicationFirewallConfiguration  = $null`
> 10.  `$appGW.ForceFirewallPolicyAssociation  = $true`
> 11.  `Set-AzApplicationGateway  -ApplicationGateway $AppGw`
> ```

Once you finish updating the Application Gateway using the above script. you can  also be able update the backend pools of application gateway by using below commands:

```
az network application-gateway address-pool create --resource-group <resoruce group > --gateway-name <app-gate-name> --name MyAddressPool1 --servers <address>
```

I tried in my environment it is successfully updated:

[image]

[image]

Following that, you can use the Azure portal to switch the Application Gateway SKU back to WAF V2 and attach the WAF policy to it.

Reference:
[Cannot renew Certificate in Azure Application Gateway with WAF - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/911237/cannot-renew-certificate-to-application-gateway-wi.html) by GitaraniSharmaMSFT-4262